# Dynamic Filters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm using Office 2013, and working on a worksheet in Excel.

My question is, is there a way to create a dynamic filter in Excel?

To explain in more detail, I have a dynamic worksheet, where upon opening the user will get a few drop-down options. After the user has selected one option from each of the drop-downs, the worksheet will display a table of data based on the user's inputs. The user can change their selections from the drop-downs after the table has been displayed, and can also clear their selections. If they clear their selection, the table will disappear.

Now, the first column in the result Table will contain Text values, but can also contain blanks. These values or blanks are all decided based on the user's selections in the previously mentioned drop-downs, which are displayed permanently to the left of the table. I want to add a filter to this first column of the result table (and to the rest of the table with it) such that only the non blank cells are displayed in the table every time the drop-downs are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your need correct, I can give you this solution:

1. For getting a better result make your range to `Table`.
2. Select `Power View` from `Insert` items;
   [image]
3. A sheet `Power View 1` will added to your `workbook`;
   [image]
4. From right pane select `Table1` and its fields;
5. From Filter pane select as you want for filtering.